# PANDAS code for calculating distance between waypoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, geospatial

I've written some python code designed to take a csv of waypoints for a series of trips, and calculate the distance of each trip by the sum of the distance between the waypoints.

An example csv might be:

```
9e77d54918dd25c3f9d2e5354ec86666,0,2015-10-01T14:14:15.000Z,45.0988,7.5811,,
9e77d54918dd25c3f9d2e5354ec86666,1,2015-10-01T14:17:15.000Z,45.0967,7.5793,,
9e77d54918dd25c3f9d2e5354ec86666,2,2015-10-01T14:20:15.000Z,45.1012,7.6144,,
9e77d54918dd25c3f9d2e5354ec86666,3,2015-10-01T14:23:15.000Z,45.0883,7.6479,,
9e77d54918dd25c3f9d2e5354ec86666,4,2015-10-01T14:26:15.000Z,45.0774,7.6444,,
ect...
```

I've got code working, using pandas and numpy, however I'm entirely self-taught and I want to know if there's any serious or obvious mistakes I'm using that might make my code inefficient. It currently takes quite a while to run, I'm guessing because of my for loop. The code I'm using is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import radians, cos, sqrt

def dist(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2): #short distances using Equirectangular approximation
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    x = (lon2 - lon1) * cos( 0.5*(lat2+lat1) )
    y = lat2 - lat1
    D = 6371 * sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    return D 

waypoint = pd.read_csv('TripRecordsReportWaypoints.csv',sep=',',header=None, usecols=[0,3,4], names=['TripID','Lat','Lon'])
output = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['TripID','Distance','No. of Waypoints'])

tripList = waypoint['TripID'].tolist() #creates list of tripids
tripList = list(set(tripList)) #makes list unique

for ID in tripList:
    temp = waypoint.loc[waypoint['TripID'] == ID] #creates a temporary dataframe with all waypoint for each trip

    temp['endLat'] = temp['Lat'].shift(periods=-1) #adds two columns with next waypoints lat and lon
    temp['endLon'] = temp['Lon'].shift(periods=-1) 

    temp['Distance']=np.vectorize(dist)(temp['Lat'],temp['Lon'],temp['endLat'],temp['endLon']) #calculates distance, can change function 'dist' for more accuracy
    SumDist = temp['Distance'].sum() #calculates the total distance
    trpId = temp['TripID'].iloc[0] #takes the tripid
    wpcount = temp.shape[0] #length of dataframe
    temp2 = pd.DataFrame([[trpId,SumDist,wpcount]],columns=['TripID','Distance','No. of Waypoints']) #creates a single row dataframe with the total distance
    output = pd.concat([output,temp2]) #adds the row to the output
output.to_csv('TripDistances.csv',sep=',')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be greatly simplified when using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). This function groups a dataframe by some key(s) and then allows performing functions that act on the whole sub-dataframe (henceforth called group) using `apply` or apply some aggregating function to single columns of that group using `aggregate`.

For this to work, we need to define a `dist` function that can take a `DataFrame` and calculate the total distance of that `DataFrame`. Note that I will assume that each trip is sorted within the csv, otherwise you will have to add this there as well.

To make the `dist` function, we need to make sure all functions it uses are vectorized, so I will be using `np.cos` and `np.sqrt` instead of the `math` ones. I also defined a constant, `EARTH_RADIUS`, because you might want to change the precision on that at some point. In any case, it is currently a magic number and giving it a name helps a lot. Or maybe you move to Mars at some point and need to use a different radius :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


EARTH_RADIUS = 6371  # km


def total_dist(group):
    lat = np.radians(group.Lat)
    lon = np.radians(group.Lon)
    endLon = lon.shift(-1)
    endLat = lat.shift(-1)
    x = (endLon - lon) * np.cos(0.5 * (endLat + lat))
    y = endLat - lat
    D = EARTH_RADIUS * np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    return D.sum()
```

Note that the conversion to radians is not as nice anymore, but we gain the ability to process a whole trip at a time!

Now we define a helper function to output not only the dist, but also the number of waypoints (by using `len`):

```
def trip_statistics(trip):
    return pd.Series({"Distance": total_dist(trip),
                      "No. of Waypoints": len(trip)})
```

Now the only thing left to do is `apply` this function to all groups and reset the index to get `TripID` back as a column and not just as an index:

```
waypoint = pd.read_csv('TripRecordsReportWaypoints.csv', sep=',',
                       header=None, usecols=[0, 3, 4],
                       names=['TripID', 'Lat', 'Lon'])
output = waypoint.groupby("TripID").apply(trip_statistics)
output.reset_index().to_csv('TripDistances.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Note that I added `index=False` to avoid writing the row index to the output file.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm not sure what you mean by vectorized functions though. What differences would using math make?

Comment: @JoshuaKidd `math.cos` can take only a `float` (or any other single number) as argument. `np.cos` takes a vector/`numpy.array` of `floats` and acts on all of them at the same time. For the `math` one you would have to write an explicit loop (e.g. `lat = np.array([math.radians(x) for x in group.Lat])` instead of what I wrote in the answer. The numpy implementation is written in C, whereas the explicit loop is (mostly) written in Python. The numpy implementation is a lot faster (especially as the length of the vector grows).